# Getting the absolute page number with zref and latex3

Tags: page-numbering, expansion, latex3, zref

Within a larger project, I want to set a string equal to the current absolute page number, like this

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\usepackage{zref-user}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{intfig} { > { \SplitArgument { 1 } { , } } m!o }
{
  % Apparently, this is required because the page number isn't fixed until shipout.
  \zlabel{ randomname }

  % Error: "\zref doesn't match its definition."
  \str_set:Nx \l_intfig_filespec_str { \zref[abspage]{ randomname } }

  % This works as expected.
  \zref[abspage]{ randomname }
}{ }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{intfig}{bogus}
\end{intfig}
\end{document}
```

There is something going here, probably having to do with expansion, that I can't figure out. On *that* subject, maybe someone knows of a document that's more expository than the `interface3` document, which is cryptic when you're starting out.

If it matters, in the actual code, the `randomname` used above will be a string too, like `\l_intfig_figname_str`. I wanted to keep the example minimal.

Comment: `\zref` is not expandable, since it issues a warning in case of undefined references. `zref` does have some expandable commands for data extraction which can be used, though.

Comment: Also, at least in the MWE, `\refstepcounter` was never run before `\zlabel` is called. You'll get a correct abspage, but not quite a correct default reference. If you only need abspage, you should probably used `\zref@labelbyprops{randomname}{abspage}`.

Comment: I'd recommend you do include the `\l_intfig_figname_str` in your MWE, since your doubt seems to be about expansion control in extracting the reference data. You'll probably get an answer which is more directly useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the expandable version of `\zref`, in this case `\zref@extractdefault`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[papersize={4cm,6cm},margin=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\usepackage{zref-user}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \g__intfig_unique_int

\NewDocumentEnvironment{intfig} { > { \SplitArgument { 1 } { , } } m!o }
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g__intfig_unique_int
  \zlabel{ intfig-\int_to_arabic:n { \g__intfig_unique_int } }
  \str_set:Nx \l_intfig_filespec_str
   {
    \use:c { zref@extractdefault } { intfig-\int_to_arabic:n { \g__intfig_unique_int } } { abspage } { 0 }
   }
  \str_use:N \l_intfig_filespec_str
}{ }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{intfig}{bogus}
  Text
\end{intfig}

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\begin{intfig}{bogus}
  Text
\end{intfig}

\end{document}
```

The `geometry` package is just to make a smaller picture.

The integer variable is used to provide a unique label to every call of the environment.

[image]

Comment: The use of a counter so that every label is unique is a nice touch.

Comment: @RandallFairman Since you don't seem interested in reusing the label, it would be a nuisance to need creating one for each call of the environment. But your application might be different.

Answer (score 2):

`\zref` is not expandable, so using the `x` expansion to get the reference value is not the way to go. `zref` itself offers plenty of other alternatives, I think the one which most immediately does what you seem to want it to do is `\zref@def@extract` (let Oberdiek handle expansion control for you ;-). An example using it:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\usepackage{zref-user}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Ensure zref@unique exists
\zref@require@unique

\NewDocumentEnvironment{intfig} { > { \SplitArgument { 1 } { , } } m!o }
{
  % You probably want this (or some other dedicated counter)
  \refstepcounter { zref@unique }

  % If you only need abspage.
  \zref@labelbyprops { randomname } { abspage }
  % or \zlabel if you really need a full reference.
  % \zlabel{ randomname }

  % This will extract the abspage property and store it in the \l_tmpa_tl
  % variable.
  \zref@def@extract { \l_tmpa_tl } { randomname } { abspage }

  % For demonstration purposes only.
  \tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
}{ }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{intfig}{bogus}
  Foo
\end{intfig}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by a "full reference" versus "only need abspage?" The goal is to obtain the absolute page number (so that a preface, TOC, etc. are part of the tally) as a string that will then be written to a file -- the writing to a file part I have.

Comment: @RandallFairman When you use `\zlabel`, your label will contain all the properties in `zref`'s `main` property list. By default, that will be `default` and `page`. The `abspage` module will add `abspage` there too. Other modules may add further properties. So, if you only need the `abspage` property, you can make things a little lighter, by setting just that. To see the difference in the works, test both alternatives, and examine the resulting .aux file.